# using canvas when creating an IPHONE APP using HTML5 CSS and JQUERY

Tags: jquery, iphone, html, css

I am working on APP for IPHONE and I wanted to try something different.  I want to create all of my images and graphics (buttons and other) using canvas.  Will this work once it is turned into an iPhone app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safari on the iPhone does support HTML5 canvas.

Comment: Does it work when you create an app though?  Just double checking.  The app would be an actual iPhone app.  I know safari supports it.  I assume iPhone apps do, but I can't fine a definitive answer.  Thanks

Comment: Native apps are written in Objective C, so they have their own drawing elements and operations.  _WebApps_ use HTML5 and CSS, and those work fine.

Comment: Can I just wrap the html in objective c using xcode and create a native app that way?